# Is Local/Roaming storage in WinRT secured?

Tags: c#, windows-8, windows-runtime

How is WinRT storing the following value? Is it in plain text? Or is there some kind of encryption in place?

```
var localSettings = Windows.Storage.ApplicationData.Current.LocalSettings;

// Create a simple setting

localSettings.Values["exampleSetting"] = "Hello Windows";

// Read data from a simple setting

Object value = localSettings.Values["exampleSetting"];
```

Similarly for roaming.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, there's no built-in encryption or compression with local/roaming settings. You'd need to add that yourself, perhaps using the Windows.Security.Cryptography APIs. There's also the Windows.Storage.PasswordVault that can basically store key-value pairs that also get roamed if the user allows roamed passwords via PC settings.